# Get the status of Scripting on a site

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I have written a set of PowerShell code to enable scripting on a site collection. Now, what is the possible way to check the current status of Scripting. Can anyone please provide me a PowerShell code?

```
$adminUPN="user@domain.onmicrosoft.com"
$orgName="domain"
$Url = "https://domain.sharepoint.com/"
$userCredential = Get-Credential -UserName $adminUPN -Message "Type the password."
Connect-SPOService -Url https://$orgName-admin.sharepoint.com -Credential $userCredential

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")


Set-SPOsite $Url -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0
```

The above is the code which I have written for enabling scripting in SharePoint O365 site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to run the below command :

```
$Url = "https://domain.sharepoint.com/"
Get-SPOSite -Identity $Url -Detailed | select DenyAddAndCustomizePages
```

It will give you the scripting status. It will be set as `Enabled` for Modern team and communication sites. For classic sites, the status will show `Disabled` after you have run the commands mentioned in the question .

[image]

Comment: Hi Gautam, thank you for your response. Can you please let me know if the code which I have used to Enable scripting is correct? Because I am getting the value as "Disabled".

Comment: Yes, its correct.  It will enable custom scripts on your site collection.

Comment: It didn't work for me though. :'( 
https://ibb.co/bJctnb

Comment: I think it worked, its showing up  `Disabled` which is expected. Now custom scripts are enabled on your site collection. To verify , go to site settings. Under the `Web Designer Galleries` section, `Solutions` link will show up.

Comment: Thanks a lot. "Solutions" link is present at the same location. Can you please tell me why is it "Expected"? And any links where I can see the changes comes after enabling scripting?

Comment: I meant `Disabled` = Allow custom scripts :) , i know its sounds a bit weird. When you run the command, lots of other things are allowed as well. Do check this [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Allow-or-prevent-custom-script-1f2c515f-5d7e-448a-9fd7-835da935584f)

Comment: I understand. I really am very stupid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68404/discussion-between-anand-and-gautam-sheth).