# Content editor webpart not available in newly created Team sites in Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, content-editor-web-part

Content editor is not becoming available in newly created Team sites in office 365.

I enabled `SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure` in site collection features and `SharePoint Server Publishing` in Site features. `Custom Script` is also enabled from SharePoint admin.

I tried all the steps suggested in this [question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/121115/)

Even after all these, I am not able to add Content Editor webpart.

Have they deprecated Content Editor Webpart in Office 365? or have I missed any steps?

Comment: Is this the classic team site in O563?

Comment: If you are using modern experience then content editor webpart is not available. Instead, if you want to add only text, you can use text webpart available in modern experience. But if you want to add HTML/Script you will need to use react script editor webpart as suggested by Gautam in his answer below.

Answer (score 2):

It is not supported in the modern experience.

While your OOTB modern webparts and custom SPFx webparts work in classic sites, the classic webparts dont work in Modern sites.

There is also a [uservoice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/32122990-modern-content-editor-web-part) which you can upvote which is requesting the CEWP capabilities in Modern sites.

You can however use your html/css/js content in Modern pages using using [react script editor](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor) webpart which works quite similar to CEWP/SEWP.

Answer (score 1):

Content Editor Webpart is not deprecated in Office 365.

After enable Custom Script  from SharePoint admin, it might take 24 hour to take effect.

Besides, try to create a new team site and compare whether the issue still exists.

Reference:

https://aslamsumayya.wordpress.com/2017/10/17/content-editor-and-script-editor-web-part-missing-in-sharepoint-online-root-site-collection/

https://www.turtle.works/knowledge/content-editor-web-part-missing/

Comment: For your issue, make sure you allow custom script on that particular site collection by using the following Microsoft PowerShell command: Set-SPOsite <SiteURL> -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0

Reference:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/allow-or-prevent-custom-script?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fAllow-or-prevent-custom-script-1f2c515f-5d7e-448a-9fd7-835da935584f

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/229739/get-the-status-of-scripting-on-a-site